# Cross-platform C# application with Gstreamer

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, gstreamer

I have a very specific question. I want to create a multimedia multi-platform application on C# which will use Mono. Is it possible to create a C# Mono application which will use gstreamer-sharp or "pure" gstreamer or something like "glued" gstreamer on these platforms: Windows, Mac OS, Linux, iOS, Android? I think I can use Pinvoke, but maybe it can be implemented more elegant? I know, it's maybe really strange question(or maybe not ;-)) but which variants I have?

Answer (score 0):

This should be do-able. The gstreamer SDK is available for all of your required platforms and is documented/can be installed from here:
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+the+SDK